# DECE Common File Format (UltraViolet)

Tags: audio, audio-streaming

I need to parse common file format (DECE CFF). Is there any specification available for this?

Also, I have some .uvu file, how can I play this. Is there any player available for this?

I know CFF is based on Fragmented MP4, but how to parse .uvu files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the public specification for how they extended the mp4 file format:
http://www.uvvuwiki.com/images/c/cb/CFFMediaFormat-1.1r1.pdf

There's more on this page:
http://www.uvvu.com/uv-for-business.php